# Dropdown Select resetting to first value when navigating to URL route

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Just started building my own React site after many circles of tutorials. I have a simple dropdown select that navigates to a specific route/URL when selected. However I'd like the select to stay at the URL that the user navigated to ( so when the "Ants" page is selected, the dropdown goes to "Ants" or "Bees" etc). Here's my code. I tried a bunch of different things as well as. using "useNavigate" from Router & a few other methods to no avail. Anyone have any ideas? Thank you and sorry if this is a dumb question.

Here's my Dropdown component code

```
export default function DropDown() {
  function onChange(e) {
    window.location.href = `/${e.target.value}`;
  };

  return (
    <div className="select-container">
      <p> <label htmlFor="pests">Choose a pest: </label></p>
      <div class="select-dropdown">
        <select onChange={onChange}>
          <option value="ants">Ants</option>
          <option value="wasps">Wasps</option>
          <option value="mice">Mice</option>
        </select>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Here's the code from my app.js (Router)

```
function App() {
  return (
    <div className="main">
      <Header />
      <NavbarBasic />
      {/* These are the main routes and subpages */}
      <Routes>
        <Route path='/' element={<Home />} />
        <Route path='/about' element={<About />} />
        <Route path='/pests-we-treat' element={<Pests />} />
        <Route path='/services' element={<Services />} />
        <Route path='/contact' element={<Contact />} />
        <Route path='/ants' element={<Ants />} />
        <Route path='/wasps' element={<Wasps />} />
        <Route path='/roaches' element={<Roaches />} />
        <Route path='/bedbugs' element={<Bedbugs />} />
        <Route path='/bees' element={<Bees />} />
        <Route path='/mice' element={<Mice />} />
        <Route path='/flies' element={<Flies />} />
      </Routes>
    </div>
  );
}


  return (
    <div className="select-container">
      <p> <label htmlFor="pests">Choose a pest: </label></p>
      <div class="select-dropdown">
        <select onChange={onChange}>
          <option value="ants">Ants</option>
          <option value="wasps">Wasps</option>
          <option value="mice">Mice</option>
        </select>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}
```

and for posterity here's my code with the actual Navbar

```
export default function NavbarBasic() {

  const Hamburger = () => {
    var x = document.getElementById("myTopnav");
    if (x.className === "topnav") {
      x.className += " responsive";
    } else {
      x.className = "topnav";
    }
  }


  return (
    <div className="topnav" id="myTopnav">
      <NavLink to="/">Home</NavLink>
      <NavLink to="/about">About</NavLink>
      <NavLink to="/contact">Contact</NavLink>
      <NavLink to="/pests-we-treat">Pests We Treat</NavLink>

      <div className="dropdown">
        <button className="dropbtn">Pests We Treat
        <CaretDownIcon className="caret" />
        </button>

        <div className="dropdown-content">
          <a href="/ants" to="/">Ants</a>
          <a href="/bedbugs" to="/">Bedbugs</a>
          <a href="/flies" to="/">Flies</a>
          <a href="/roaches" to="/">Roaches</a>
          <a href="/wasps" to="/">Wasps</a>
        </div>
      </div>
      <a href="#" className="icon" onClick={Hamburger}>&#9776;</a>
    </div >
  )
}
```

Comment: Can you please provide a code sandbox for your use case ?

Answer (score 0):

Pay attention to values of options! In this case I added '/'

```js
 let currentPath = window.location.pathname
 
 return (
    ...
        <select onChange={onChange} defaultValue={currentPath}>
          <option value="/ants">Ants</option>
          <option value="/wasps">Wasps</option>
          <option value="/mice">Mice</option>
        </select>
      ...
  );
```

Comment: Thank you but this returns an invalid URL with the "/"

Comment: let currentPath = window.location.pathname.substring(1) and remove '/' in option values

Comment: Oleg thank you!! works like a charm